# How add confirmation box with password in php before deleting?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a table in my php that shows the data of a table in my database: Username, emails, etc and I have added a delete option too. The delete option works correctly and displays a confirmation message before removing. However, I want to add a confirmation message with a needed password when the user clicks on delete option.

Every time I press the delete option, a confirmation message appears to delete the data I want, however I would like the confirmation message to have a password to completely delete the message. I would like you to show a message type: `confirm ('Please confirm deletion and enter the password to delete');`.

Does anyone know how it could be done? Thank you.

This is what I have:

index.php:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3"><h2>Users</h2></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Name </th>
        <th> Email </th>
        <th> Delete</th>
    </tr>

<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users"; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows==0){

    echo "No users";
}else{
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>".$row["username"]."</td><td>".$row["email"]."</td><td><a class='eliminate' onClick=\"javascript: return confirm('Please confirm deletion');\" href=\"delete.php?id=".$row['id']."\">X</a></td></tr>";
    }
}

?>
</table>
```

delete.php:

```
<?php
include('Conexion.php');// Check connection with DB
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$id = $_GET['id']; // $id is defined

mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM users WHERE id='".$id."'");
mysqli_close($conn);
header("Location: index.php");
?>
```

I was thinking of introducing a script like this:

```
    <script>
function myFunction() {
  var txt;
  var password = prompt("Please confirm deletion and enter the password to delete:", "Password");
  if (password == null || password == "" || password != "realpassword") {
    txt = "User cancelled the prompt.";
  } else {
    txt = "Are you sure?";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Password would need to be stored on server which would require using ajax and promises also. This question is far too broad

Comment: The only safe way to do this would be to do the delete as an AJAX call, so you dont keep passwords in the javascript.

Comment: You could write a javascript dialog to ask for the password and give the "Are you sure" message to the user

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's what I think is best. I don't know about Ajax. Do you know of any example where can I see how it's done?

Comment: Not off hand, but I would start on the jQuery site. A google seach should get you to any number of tutorials

Answer (score 1):

You have a large selection of methods to do it, but I'd say the simplest ones are:

**Ajax + Prompt :**

[Prompt](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt) allows you to create an alert box in which you can include some text. Then you get this text and perform an [Ajax](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) call to a PHP script that will delete the user (basically similar to your delete.php but without the header() function call)

**Intermediate PHP page**

You can also use another PHP page with a form where the user is asked to type the password, and then proceed normally to the delete.php page if it is correct. Of course you'll need to pass the `$id`to the intermediate page (as a GET variable for example) to do so.

Comment: I have edited the question with a script that uses a function that asks for a password. Do you know how to  proceed to eliminate after the 'Are you sure?' message?